# Mongoose, Supertest: Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, jestjs, supertest

I'm trying to use jest and supertest to test my node.js + express application. However,
I keep getting the error message "Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed."

If I remove `mongoose.connect(...)` from `app.js` everything's working fine, but I need the database...

Here's my code:

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const keys = require('./config/keys');

mongoose.connect(keys.MONGO_URI, 
  { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

const app = express();

app.get('/user', (req, res) => {
  res.send("success");
})

//...

module.exports = app;
```

app.test.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = require('../src/app');
const request = require('supertest');

describe('GET /user', function () {
    afterAll(() => mongoose.disconnect());
    it('has respononse status code 200', function (done) {
        request(app)
            .get('/user')
            .expect(200, done);
    });
});
```

error message:

```
> jest

 PASS  tests/app.test.js (6.798 s)
  GET /user
    √ has respononse status code 200 (22 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.875 s, estimated 7 s
Ran all test suites.

Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.

ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down.

      at BufferList.Readable (node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:179:22)
      at BufferList.Duplex (node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js:67:12)
      at new BufferList (node_modules/bl/bl.js:33:16)
      at new MessageStream (node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:35:21)
      at new Connection (node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:54:28)
C:\Users\XXX\server\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:111
  var isDuplex = stream instanceof Duplex;
                        ^

TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable
    at new ReadableState (C:\Users\XXX\server\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:111:25)
    at BufferList.Readable (C:\Users\XXX\server\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:183:25)
    at BufferList.Duplex (C:\Users\XXX\server\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_duplex.js:67:12)
    at new BufferList (C:\Users\XXX\server\node_modules\bl\bl.js:33:16)      
    at new MessageStream (C:\Users\XXX\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:35:21)
    at new Connection (C:\Users\XXX\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:54:28)
    at C:\Users\XXX\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:36:29
    at callback (C:\Users\XXX\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:280:5)
    at TLSSocket.connectHandler (C:\Users\XXX\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:325:5)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:433:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:327:20)
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1527:10)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:327:20)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:932:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:706:12)
npm ERR! code 1
```

**Things I've tried:**

- I ran Jest with '--detectOpenHandles', but it didn't give me any additional information.
- There's no app.listen(PORT) (I have a separate server.js file for that)
- I've added the following to the package.json:

package.json

```
"jest": {
  "testEnvironment": "node"
}
```

Comment: detectOpenHandles isn't supposed to solve it but to expose the cause. Did it not add anything to the output? It's not evident that Mongoose is the problem. You disconnect from it. And other relevant things were omitted. What is `...`? If there's server listener and you don't unlisten it, it's obviously the problem. What happens in `/users`? The question is offtopic without https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: @EstusFlask I've updated the post and added the full error message. detectOpenHandles didn't add anything, there's no server listener and /users just sends a success message.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, mongoose hadn't established a connection when I called `mongoose.disconnect();` and this cause all the errors, so I added this to my code:

```
beforeAll((done) => {
    if(!mongoose.connection.db){
        mongoose.connection.on('connected', done)
    } else {
        done();
    }
}, 20000);
```

Comment: Yes, the error suggests that it's the problem. This isn't needed under normal circumstances because Mongoose chains a connection promise for the rest of operations. This can be specific to Mongoose or Mongo version. Probably a bug.